# array manipulation (inserting elements)

Tags: c, arrays

what is the problem in this code, i can't insert more than 9 elements in the array ? this code is supposed to let user enter up to 100 elements different elements in the array .

Here is the inserting Function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int y = 0;
void insert(int a[])
{
    printf("enter an element to insert\n");
    int p, i, x = 0, z = 0, k = 0;
    scanf("%i", &x);
    if (y < 100)
    {
        if (y != 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == x)
                {
                    printf("Element %d already exists, No change", x);
                    z = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (z == 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
                {
                    if (x < a[i])
                    {
                        p = i;
                        y++;
                        k = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (z == 0 && k == 0)
                {
                    y++;
                    p = y - 1;
                    a[p] = x;
                }

                if (z == 0 && k == 1)
                {
                    for (i = (y - 1); i > p; i--)
                    {
                        a[i] = a[i - 1];
                    }
                    a[p] = x;
                    printf("\nElement %d is inserted   \n y is %d", x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            y++;
            a[y - 1] = x;
            printf("\nElement %d is inserted", x);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("array is full");
}
  int main()
{
   int x=0;
   int a[y];
   while(x!=2)
   {
      printf("\nEnter your choice: 1) insert 2)exit \n");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      switch (x)
      {
         case 1:
         insert(a);
         break;
         case 2:
         printf("Goodbye");
         break;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please — post the code properly indented.  It is hard to read and understand when it is not properly indented.  Get the code to post ready, making sure there are no tabs in it.  Copy and paste it into the edit window, ignoring the preview, and making sure that it looks correct (you don't have any tabs in it, do you?).  Select the code, and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.  Now look at the preview, and make sure it still looks OK.  If you had no tabs in it, it should be OK.  Tabs really spoil things, in case you hadn't guessed.

Comment: You should generally finish messages with a newline, rather than (or perhaps as well as) starting with a newline.  On many types of computer, the output won't appear until you generate a newline.

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Show us caller side code.

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names. It's impossible to understand what variables `k` and `z` represent in this code.

Comment: How big is the array that you declared or allocated in the caller?

Comment: if z becomes 1 , this means that the element already exits in the array
and if k becomes = 1, this means that there is no smaller elements in the array .

Comment: the size of array starts with y = 0, and each time the insert function is called , y will be incremented .

Comment: `int a[y];` is `int a[0];` : Arrays are not automatically extended in C.

Comment: when the function insert is called , y will be incremented .

Comment: Y will be incremented, but the array won't be recreated. You create it once, make sure you create a proper sized array.

Answer (score 0):

the size of the array must be known in advance. in my case the size is 100 (int a[100];), or there will be overflow.